# How nodes work in Java?

Tags: java, nodes

I have codes as following from the textbook. And the codes intend to remove a node.

```
Node<String> nodeRef = head.next;
nodeRef.next = nodeRef.next.next;
```

What does `Node<String> nodeRef = head.next;` actually do here?
Does `nodeRef` copy the `head.next` node item?
If so, does it mean `head.next` point both to `nodeRef` and the original `head.next`?

Or `Node<String> nodeRef = head.next;` just give a name to the head.next instead of creating a new node?

Still get confused how nodes work. Could someone explain?

Comment: Is there an `import some.package.Node;` line in the book? Can you [edit] your question to include this?

Comment: Yes, I'll guess that you're looking at a data structures text that is implementing a linked list of Nodes.  The head in this case is the first Node in the linked list.  It has a reference to the next one in the List.  You iterate through the List by starting at the head and walking down each subsequent next Node.

Comment: @shoover No, that's how it appears to be.

Comment: @duffymo you are right. I am confused if the "Node<String> nodeRef = head.next;" actually makes a new copy of the head.next, "nodeRef.next = nodeRef.next.next; " will not remove the item.

Comment: No, it doesn't create a copy.  It just returns the reference to the next Node in the chain.  If the next Node is null, you've reached the end.  Please have a look at java.util.List: it's an interface that describes what all good abstractions of the List type should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Nodes" is immaterial; these are simply references to objects. Replace `Node` with any other reference type and the question is precisely the same.

```java
Node nodeRef = head.next;
```

This sets `nodeRef` as a reference to whatever is in `head.next`. It doesn't copy anything.

`head.next` doesn't change at all unless you actually change it.

*To address one of your comments:*

`nodeRef.next = nodeRef.next.next` will do just what it says; instead of referring to the original `nodeRef.next` it will now refer to `nodeRef.next.next`.

The object referenced by the original `nodeRef.next` will no longer be iterated over, since no node points to it. It may or may not be eligible for GC depending on if anything else has a reference to it.

(Other nodes *could* actually reference it, like if circular lists are allowed.)

Comment: If `nodeRef` points to the `Node` with `7` in a linked list that looks like `7 -> 8 -> 10`, then `nodeRef.next = nodeRef.next.next` will make the `Node` with `7` point to the `Node` with `10` instead of the one with `8`. So now your list will look like `7 -> 10`.

Comment: If nodeRef is just a reference, "nodeRef.next = nodeRef.next.next;" will just change the nodeRef.next instead of the head.next.next( as nodeRef=head.next). So I cannot see how thing is removed here, because  only nodeRef.next point into a different place, instead of the original nodes

Comment: If `nodeRef = head.next` then `nodeRef.next` is the same as `head.next.next`. `nodeRef` *is* `head.next`, they reference the same object. If you change stuff from `nodeRef` you're still touching whatever `head.next` referenced. I'd strongly recommend drawing a simple picture with boxes and lines that represents a linked list, e.g., https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4b/CPT-LinkedLists-addingnode.svg/474px-CPT-LinkedLists-addingnode.svg.png, and stepping through the code in your head or on paper.

Comment: `nodeRef = head.next`, right? So what's `nodeRef.next`? Replace `nodeRef` with its equivalent, `head.next`: `head.next.next`.

Comment: So nodeRef is the same thing as head.next with a new name, but it is not a new node with two links to the head.next.data and head.next.next, right?

Comment: And when I change nodeRef.next, the head.next.next will change as nodeRef.next changes. Is that right. Just want to make sure.

Comment: @ksdawq You are correct, `nodeRef = head.next` is the same as giving `head.next` a second name. The **only** way to create a new node is to use the `new` keyword.